# How would you handle two way relations in relational-pouch?

Tags: relational-database, pouchdb

Is this schema valid in relational-pouch (especially the relations between obj and objList):

```
let schema = [
            {
                singular: 'obj', plural: 'objs', relations: {
                'objList': { belongsTo: 'objList' },
                'attributesEditable': { belongsTo: 'attributesEditable' },
                'attributesViewable': { belongsTo: 'attributesViewable' },
            },
            },
            {
                singular: 'objList', plural: 'objLists', relations: {
                'objs': { hasMany: 'obj' },
                'obj': { belongsTo: 'obj' },
            },
            },
            {
                singular: 'attributesEditable', plural: 'attributesEditables', relations: {
                'obj': { belongsTo: 'obj' },
            },
            },
            {
                singular: 'attributesViewable', plural: 'attributesViewables', relations: {
                'obj': { belongsTo: 'obj' },
            },
            },
        ];
```

What I want:
[image]

My App starts with an entry point which is an obj and this has one objList with many obj in it and so on.

Comment: Can a ObjList be inside of another ObjList?

Comment: @Ramon-san no only an obj has an objlist and that has further objs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one realtion between objList and obj, and should declare it in both parts. But in objList declared two relations. Try this code:

```
[...]
{
    singular: 'obj', plural: 'objs', relations: {
        'objList': { belongsTo: 'objList' },
        'attributesEditable': { belongsTo: 'attributesEditable' },
        'attributesViewable': { belongsTo: 'attributesViewable' },
    },
},
{
    singular: 'objList', plural: 'objLists', relations: {
        'objs': { hasMany: 'obj' }
    },
[...]
```